# Split and merge columns in Tableau

Tags: merge, split, tableau-api, data-analysis

I Know how to split the country column into multiple columns(Using custom split I split them on the comma's) but I am not sure how to merge them like shown below(What I want). Any help is greatly appreciated

```
                                  **What I have**                           
ID        Type                                        Country               
1        TV Show                               USA, UK, Spain, Sweden                      
2        Movie                                 USA, India
3        Movie                                 USA
4        TV Show                               Bulgaria, USA
5        Movie                                 Sweden, Norway
6        Movie                                 UK, USA
7        TV Show                               Germany
8        TV Show                               India
9        Movie                                 USA, India
10       Movie                                 USA



**What I want**
  USA 
  UK 
  Spain
  Sweden   
  USA
  India
  USA
  Bulgaria
  USA
  Sweden
  Norway
  UK
  USA
  Germany
  India
  USA
  India
  USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually something you can do in the datasource pane, even though it may not make much sense "inside" Tableau for "data handling".

As you said the first step is splitting your Country column; doing so, for each row you will get N columns where N equals the number of country for the row having the highest number of countries (4 in your example).
Rows having just 1 country will have just the first column with a value and the rest will be null value columns.

Once you have done the first step, you need to pivot your data selecting those N columns, right-click and select pivot.
Doing that you will get N*M rows where N is the maximum number of countries per original row (4) and M is the number of your original rows (10).

Since, as said before there could be null values, the final step should filtering out all "new rows" having null values.

Comment: When I select the N Columns and right click the pivot option isn't shown.

Comment: You're right: any chance you can achieve the first part (split) prior to land on Tableau Desktop... let's say Tableau Prep?

Comment: Got it. Since it's calculated field you cannot pivot so once you convert it to normal field you can pivot.

Comment: yes, that's why I asked if you can split first and then take care of the pivoting in the data-source pane using Tableau Desktop